# What really happened in the chemistry lab?

Tags: plot-explanation, october-sky

At some point in the movie October Sky (1999) flames were created. I didn't clearly get it. So What really happened in the chemistry lab?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pair of boys poured chemicals, watered downed, down the drain to dispose of it. A different boy then dropped a match down a different drain. The movie depicts this as igniting the chemicals, ***accidentally*** causing all the sinks to catch on fire.

Of course, the chemicals in the scene, when watered down like that, wouldn't react that way. It also ignores plumbing, as the u trap of the sinks should have water in them and that would also prevent all the sinks from catching on fire.